# React-native ios application build with expo returns error 413 with publish

Tags: ios, react-native, build, expo

I have problem with running build react-native application based on expo

`expo build:ios`
returns

```
Request failed with status code 413
Error: Request failed with status code 413
    at createError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:237:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:205:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1154:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)
```

Thanks a lot for any advice

Answer (score 0):

Publishing in installment worked for me.
I published several times in a row adding one more big asset each time.
Not great but worked ...